# Symfony2: Checkbox field errors are always rendered like error_bubbling = true

Tags: forms, symfony, checkbox

I have a simple user registration form with a checkbox for 'accept terms'. I have set all fields to error_bubbling=false, but the error of the checkbox is rendered in the form_errors(form) section.

Here is my entity:

```
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable, EquatableInterface
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
    * @Assert\Type("bool")
    * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"Registration"})
    */
    private $isAcceptingTOS;
    ....

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'password_required' => true,
            'validation_groups' => array('Registration', 'Default'),
        ));
    }

}
```

My form type:

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    $builder
    ->add('acceptingTOS', 'checkbox', array(
        'error_bubbling' => false,
    )),
    ....
}
```

And my template

```
<form action="{{ path('registration_create') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>

    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    {{ form_widget(form.acceptingTOS) }}
    {{ form_label(form.acceptingTOS) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.acceptingTOS) }}

    {{ form_rest(form) }}

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Any hints?

Comment: I don't understand your problem, do you want to show the error with {{ form_errors(form.acceptingTOS) }} and not with {{ form_errors(form) }} ?

Comment: Yes, I want to show the error in form_errors(form.acceptingTOS). Near the field, and not in the form errors.

Comment: Ok can you show us setDefaultOptions() method of your RegistrationType ?

Comment: added the setDefaultOptions() method in the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.

I have to use isAcceptingTOS instead of acceptingTOS in the form type and in the template.